# Can I make a QR code to site its favicon.ico?

Tags: image, browser, cross-browser, qr-code, favicon

Specifically I want to make a QR code to http://example.com be the favicon for all pages under http://example.com

Is the available resolution good enough?  How do I scale it down? Can I chop off the single pixel white border before scaling down?

Can I pack multiple resolutions -- if so what browsers would show the higher resolutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up bundling the smallest QR code I could generate 27x27 together with 3 more sizes 54x54, 81x81, and what seemed to be the default: 108x108 using imagemagick to pack them up, roughly as described here: http://bergamini.org/computers/creating-favicon.ico-icon-files-with-imagemagick-convert.html

I did not scale them because at least Chrome and Firefox were able to scale them to their needs, and this way I did not risk messing with the information in the QR code itself. Note that the QR codes go in multiples of 27x27 and the favicons go in multiples of 16x16, hence the risk of losing information when rescaling.

I do not know what happens with IE because I don't have access to it.

The previous answer incorrectly mentions 25x25 as the size of the image because it does not include the white pixel border on each size, which I cannot see as redundant because it serves a purpose in marking off the actual content of the QR code.

I did not research whether removing that 1-pixel white border can still allow a reader to read the QR-code against a variety of backgrounds by making use of the redundant loss-tolerance information in the QR-code.

I did not worry about pixel-resolutions or scanner distance and assumed that the user would be able to create ideal conditions for those factors.

I probably have useless QR-code favicon in the sense that it cannot be scanned right off the browser bar, but hey, it is a legitimate favicon from a non-QR perspective and if someone explicitly downloads the favicon.ico then they do have access to a full QR code :-)

I am accepting my own answer because the other one is less sufficient and I will be happy to switch to accepting another answer if someone comes up with a better one :)

Answer (score 1):

Favicons that are displayed by the browser in the URL bar are 16x16 which is not enough for a normal QR code (25x25). You can include a better resolution favicon and some browsers will display it in places but unless the end size on screen is large enough to scan it won't help you. You can see the minimum size you would need on screen for a scan-able code [here](http://www.qrstuff.com/blog/2011/11/23/qr-code-minimum-size).

Comment: is it true that all mainstream browsers and devices will display not more than 16x16 in the URL bar? for example, if chrome displays higher resolution, it is worth it for me

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110741/google-chrome-uses-wrong-size-of-favicon), Chrome resizes higher resolution icons to 16x16 for display in the favorites/URL bars. It looks like higher ones can be used for shortcuts as shown [here](http://nooshu.com/high-resolution-icons-for-google-chrome).

Answer (score 1):

Micro QR code is also available, its size is about 15x15 and more px, but not every QRcode reader can read that.
I tried to make this one at my homepage: http://tim.tom.ru